# How to generate a PDF file with get content from SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using dompdf library and generate the PDF file. In that PDF I have to put the content from query in database.

Comment: Hi Saravanan. Just so you know, very brief questions like this tend to be downvoted and/or closed. This is because its brevity hides the detail we need to give an answer that is likely to be useful to you (despite this, two people are bravely giving an answer anyway). Additionally, we like to see prior effort and research here, and questions that feature neither are sometimes viewed as lazy (you could have done days of research in this case, but since we cannot see it, we assume not).

Comment: Hi.  I worte the query and for get the field name and value from database. But it takes the field name and not consider the field values.              mysql_num_fields() this method is used to get the field name and mysql_fetch_row() this method is used to get the field values.

Comment: It would be most helpful, in that case, if you would put the relevant bit of your code into your question (by editing it). Hopefully you can now see why this is essential. Use the formatting tools provided please.

Comment: As @halfer said, we need something to work with. We're not psychic and only the Force is only strong in some of us

Answer (score 1):

You can use FPDF. FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Above code will generate a pdf with "Hello World!" text in it, with font arial, size 16 and bold style.
You can enter your sql query result in place of Hello World.

For more information on FPDF, go to their [official site](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this script

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "");
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to Connect MySQL: (" . $mysqli-     >connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
     }

    require_once 'dompdf-master/dompdf_config.inc.php';

  $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name");


   while ($arr_result = $result->fetch_array())
     {
      $nombre=$arr_result["nombre"];



     $html.= "
        <table>
           <tr>
             <td> $nombre </td>
           </tr></table>
     ";
    $mipdf = new DOMPDF();

    $mipdf ->set_paper("A4", "portrait");
    $mipdf ->load_html(utf8_decode($html));
    $mipdf ->render();
    $mipdf ->stream('mipdf.pdf');
       }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**fpdf**

FPDF is a PHP class that allows you to create PDF documents based on PHP.
The database connectivity can be provided by using `include`. Also, the Column headers, orientation of the pdf can be given using standardised functions of FPDF Class.

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('fpdf.php');

//Connect to your database
include("conectmysql.php");

//Create new pdf file
$pdf=new FPDF();

//Open file
$pdf->Open();

//Disable automatic page break
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

//Add first page
$pdf->AddPage();

//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis_initial = 25;

//print column titles for the actual page
$pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'CODE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 6, 'NAME', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'R', 1);

$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

//Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
$result=mysql_query('select Code, Name, Price from Products ORDER BY Code', $link);

//initialize counter
$i = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 25;

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 6;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
    if ($i == $max)
    {
        $pdf->AddPage();

        //print column titles for the current page
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
        $pdf->SetX(25);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'CODE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(100, 6, 'NAME', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'R', 1);

        //Go to next row
        $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

        //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
        $i = 0;
    }

    $code = $row['Code'];
    $price = $row['Price'];
    $name = $row['Code'];

    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $code, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(100, 6, $name, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $price, 1, 0, 'R', 1);

    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $i = $i + 1;
}

mysql_close($link);

//Create file
$pdf->Output();
?>
```